# Undefined offset: 9, Undefined variable

Tags: php

Error at this line: `$an = explode(";", $f[$i]);`
This one too: `if ($wasone)` (Undefined variable)
Any help? Thank you.

```
<?

    if ($_POST["submit"])
    {
        $a = answer();
        $out =  "Q: $ask<br>A: ".$a;
        $tile = ($cfg["scrolling"]) ? $tile : "";
        echo "$out<br>$tile";
        echo "<input name='tile' type='hidden' id='tile' value='$out<br>$tile'>";
    }

    // answers
    function answer()
    {
        global $cfg, $ask;
        $ask = (empty($ask)) ? "<empty>" : $ask;
        $kick = array("?","\n");
        $ask = str_replace($kick,"",$ask);
        $f = file($cfg["answersfile"]);
        for ($i=0; $i<=count($f); $i++)
        {
            $an = explode(";", $f[$i]);
            $a = $an[0];
            if (strstr($a,trim($ask)))
            {
                if ($wasone)
                {
                    return("Please be more concrete");
                }
                array_shift($an);
                array_pop($an);
                $ai = rand(0, count($an)-1);
                // answering
                $wasone = true;
                $retval = $an[$ai];
            }
        }
        $retval = (empty($retval)) ? "I dont understand you. Please try again." : $retval;
        return $retval;
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Kristina, see my comment under msonsona's answer. It may prove insightful for future PHP script design.

Answer (score 3):

the condition in the for loop should be

```
$count = count($f);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
```

without the '=' to ensure that only indexes accessed range from 0 to count-1

Comment: Thanks, but what should I do with the other error? The undefined variable?

Comment: you should initialize it to false before the for loop

Comment: @msonsona Refer to http://www.phpbench.com/ for why your method isn't a good practice under "Counting Loops" section. A 49000% difference in bench marking may adjust your thinking.

Comment: @Blake absolutely agree, I wasn't betting for perfomance in my solution... gonna edit, thx!

Comment: @KristinaFiedalan if you intialize the variable before the 'for' loop, I don't see how it can be undefined afterwards within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
   for ($i=0; $i<=count($f); $i++)
```

should probably be

```
   for ($i=0; $i<count($f); $i++)
```

count() returns the number of elements of $f, which is one more than the index of the last element of $f (in this case nine). You want to stop before $i gets past the index of the last element

Comment: And counting every time in a loop is very bad practice, so: `for($i = 0 , $c = count($f); $i < $c; $i++)`

Answer (score 1):

By default array **indexes begin from 0**. If `count($f) === 9`, then it means your array there has indexes `0, 1, 2 ... 8`. If you loop while `$i <= 9`, then you will try to access element with index 9 ... which is not there.